# a4j:commandButton is performing synchronously actions

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, commandbutton

I created a simple JSF example project based on [Richfaces documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces.html#sect-Component_Reference-Using_RichFaces_with_Maven-Using_the_RichFaces_project_archetype). 
I have a simple JSF page like this:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <a4j:commandButton action="#{richBean.test1}">test1</a4j:commandButton>
    <a4j:commandButton action="#{richBean.test2}">test2</a4j:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The first button calls a method that finishes in 30 seconds. The second button is quickly and can be clicked while the first method is executing.

The problem is: **when I click on the second button after clicking on the first button, the second action is just called after the first action finishes**.

Considering that both are AJAX call methods, this behaviour is correct? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: By the way, `prependId="false"` is bad. Don't ever use it. It's a leftover from JSF 1.x.

Comment: @BalusC, can you describe your comment "`prependId="false"` is bad. Don't ever use it". Note: h:form still have prependId attribute in [JSF 2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/).